# Trying to predict extreme values corresponding to rare events

Tags: regression, class-imbalance

I need some advice on methodology.

I need to predict a numeric value (claim amount) being as good as possible on high values corresponding to rare events (corporal damage, technological disaster...).

Any suggestion on methodology would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *...being as good as possible on high values ...* Could you clarify on this phrase please.

Comment: My purpose is to predict a rare event predicting the cost of that event as I know this event has high cost ( and I know every high cost events are rare ).

I tolerate predicting a small cost event as a high cost event but it is less acceptable to predict a high cost event as a low cost event : false negative cases must be avoided (but I am on a regression model not really a classification one).

The predictions should not just be good on the main most occuring events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

There is a technique called Quantile Regression, which allows you to determine the highest (or lowest) values of a variable. This is valid only if you have regressors (exogenous variables).

Comment: Looks like a good direction to follow.